# Where do you put the core of you Java application?

Tags: java, class, model-view-controller, static

I am new to `Java`, I am coming from `PHP` and `ActionScript`.

In `AS`, it is a common thing to do to put the main controller part of the software into the `main` class.

In Java, it is extremely difficult for me, because of the static property of the main class.

Because of this, I always create a non-static `"kernel"` class, which I call from the `main` class, so I do not have to deal with the static property of the `main` class. Then, I do every controlling from `kernel`.

I was wondering, if there is any, more professional solution for this.

Comment: You usually use a whole load of classes that best practice dictates be non-static. And all your actual functionality should be in classes that have a well-defined purpose besides being "main". How you organise the usually tiny bit of toplevel bootstrapping code shouldn't be too important, as long as you avoid it holding much stat.

Comment: That's pretty common. Consider the main method just as the launcher that creates and initializes your application.

Comment: @NilsH - Exactly! I just find it strage to do, as a newbie to Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That highly depends on the kind of application that you are designing, based on your situation you can always instantiate your own class in the main, then use your methods from within that instance without resorting back to the kernel solution.

```
class Foo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Foo foo = new foo();
       foo.methodA(); // no need for static modifier for the method
    }
    void methodA(){
        //your logic goes here
    }
}
```

I am not sure if that would help you, in case that is not, and you are searching for a way to compartment your code, have a look on MVP pattern which might be a bit closer to AS model.